# Pasting URL address in dataframe when scraping table in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a table, however I can only get it to paste the value of the hyper link.  I'm want the URL to be pasted instead of the value in the table.  I've worked out how to do this for a single hyperlink however I need to go through and acquire every xpath.  Is there a quicker way of doing this?

This is the code I've been working with:

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/views/all/")
cryptocurrencies <- url %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="currencies-all"]') 
                           %>% html_table(fill = T)
cryptocurrencies <- cryptocurrencies[[1]]
```

I suspect there is an argument in the html_nodes function that would allow me to paste the 'href' however I can't seem to workout how to do it.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this R package `coinmarketcapr` for the same purpose? that uses the API instead of scraping.

Comment: yes, I have - however I can't get the underlying url for the values that have links (or at least I haven't worked out how to do it).  Open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use `html_attr()` to get attributes of each note, in your case, the attribute is **href**

```
relative_paths <- page %>% 
    html_nodes(".currency-name-container") %>% 
    html_attr("href") #note it is relative path
relative_paths[1:3]
"/currencies/bitcoin/"  "/currencies/ethereum/" "/currencies/ripple/"
```

---

Once you get the relative path, you can use `jump_to()` or `follow_link()` function to do scraping on each page.

```
#display first three result
for (path in relative_paths) {
    current_session <- html_session("https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/views/all/") %>% 
        jump_to(path)
    #do something here
    print(current_session$url)
}
[1] "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
[1] "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/"
[1] "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/
```

Or can get the absolute path:

```
#or get absolute path
absolute_path <- paste0("https://coinmarketcap.com",relative_paths)
absolute_path[1:3]
[1] "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"  "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/" "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/"
```

---

Finally, you can merge it into your data frame.

Comment: This is such a great solution. It's virtually a webscraping tutorial. Any chance you could follow up with how to apply urls to gather data?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm planning to write some simple tutorials. Because while I was learning it myself I found that many materials about web scraping with R on the internet are out-dated, it really took some effort to get what you want. I can notify you if you like :)